# search for each line in another file using bash

Tags: bash

I have two text files[raw file with lines and dictionary file with keywords]. Search for each word in dictionary file in raw file, if there is a match then print the dictionary word next to matching line in raw file.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/perls-equivalent-of-grep-f.html

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `grep` to read patterns from a file using the `-f` option. You can also use the `-w` option to search for words only.

```
grep -wf dictionary.txt rawfile.txt
```